# Java sql text from database

Tags: java, sql, database

i have a label and i want to upload with text from database, i wrote a method but its show just the first item from database, i want to see all item in column

```
try {
         String sql="SELECT * FROM Arlista";
         PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()) {
             arlab1.setText(rs.getString("nev"));

         }
     }catch(Exception ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
     }
```

Comment: How is `arlab1` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(rs.next()) {
    arlab1.setText(rs.getString("nev"));
}
```

...overwrites the content of `arlab` each iteration. What you probably want to do is some kind of append to the result for each row;

```
String result = "";
while(rs.next()) {
    if(result.isEmpty()) result = rs.getString("nev");
    else result = result + "/" + rs.getString("nev");
}
arlab1.setText(result);
```

Comment: error in `else  result = result + "/" + rs.getString("nev"));`  `';' expected`

Comment: @user3633989 Edited, removed a left over `)`.